# Can't Unlock Windows IOT Process after Debug

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

Trying to debug a Universal Windows app (MyTest) for Windows IOT using Local Machine. It starts the app but only displays the X screen, not my MainPage.xaml. OK, probably some bug I made. But I can't debug it and I can't unlock it. I try to put a breakpoint at App() constructor or OnLaunched and it never hits. If I Stop Debugging the X window stays up. Worse, if I kill the X window, using the window close (button in the top right), the app looks like it stops but the MyTest.exe remains locked, forever stopping me from trying to delete the exe, rebuild project, etc.

- There is no MyTest app in the TaskManager (processes or details).
- If I terminate ApplicationFrameHost process, the X screen will go away, but the MyTest.exe file remains locked as though the exe is still in use.
- I've tried FileAssassin and it can't remove the lock.
- The only thing that unlocks MyTest.exe is rebooting the machine...kind of a pain if you only get 1 debug run before rebooting the machine each time!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using tasks you must terminate all.

example

```
BackgroundTaskDeferral _defferal;
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
     _defferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    taskInstance.Canceled += TaskInstance_Canceled;
}

private void TaskInstance_Canceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
{
    //a few reasons that you may be interested in.
    switch (reason)
    {
        case BackgroundTaskCancellationReason.Abort:
            //app unregistered background task (amoung other reasons).
            break;
        case BackgroundTaskCancellationReason.Terminating:
            //system shutdown
            break;
        case BackgroundTaskCancellationReason.ConditionLoss:
            break;
        case BackgroundTaskCancellationReason.SystemPolicy:
            break;
    }
    _defferal.Complete();
}
```

source: [Windows 10 IOT Lifecycle (or: how to property terminate a background application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429461/windows-10-iot-lifecycle-or-how-to-property-terminate-a-background-application)